# How to properly release a view after a UIView Animation ? :)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management, ios4

I have a method like the following:

```
- (void)add:(id)sender {

MyAddViewController *controller = nil;

controller = [[MyAddViewController alloc] initWithAddType:1];

//controller.delegate = self; 

// Do some animation. Slide it in from the right side of the screen.

    CGPoint initialCenter = self.view.center;
    controller.view.center = 
        CGPointMake(initialCenter.x + 320, initialCenter.y);

    // Add the subview now with it's center + 320 off the screen.
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    controller.view.center = CGPointMake(initialCenter.x, initialCenter.y); 
  //[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(aMethodToBeCalledAfterAnimationEnd:finished:context:)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

  //[controller release];
    }
```

You see I have a *controller release* as the last line in my add method. If I uncomment this line the animation completely dies and it just dumps the view into place with no animation.

Is there a better way to do *release* without having to create another method which does cleanup via *[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelect:@selector(aMethodToBeCalledAfterAnmiationEnd...* ?

Or can I do something like *setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector([controller release])* ? :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `setAnimationDidStopSelector:` is the proper way to solve the generic problem of releasing resources after an animation completes.

Take a step back and reconsider what you're doing here, though. Why are you looking to free the controller you just created? If you are only creating the controller for the purpose of getting at the view, that isn't the right way to do it. Build yourself a factory method to create your view, or use the methods in `NSBundle` to load the view from a NIB.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate: controller];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(release)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you tagged this iphone-sdk-4.0. You could use the new block-based animations to do this and any other cleanup. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW131) for details.

Comment: I've tried using the new block-based animations and I can't seem to achieve the desired effect at all. Basically I have my _currentView_ and the _incomingView_ should slide in on top of currentView. _incomingView_ is a fullsized view (320x480 or whatever) except the top half of it is transparent so that you should see the bottom of the old view when it gets added as a subview. It works with the animation code above, but I can't get it going with block-based animations. Block-based seems to also add some silly fade effect during the transition which the above does not.